# Import XML into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, xsd

I want to import xml file into flat table. The source file has slightly unusual format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <db xmlns:site="http://www.google.com">
    <params>
    <param name="parser_version" value="2"/>
    <param name="data_type" value="Events"/>
    <param name="created" value="2017-11-15T12:21:18"/>
    <param name="program_version" value="4.5.20.1092"/>
    </params>
  <tables>
    <table name="Events">
      <fields>
        <field name="UniqueID" type="Integer"/>
        <field name="ID" type="AutoInc"/>
        <field name="Date" type="Date"/>
        <field name="Time" type="Time"/>
        <field name="Code" type="Integer"/>
        <field name="UserID" type="Integer"/>
        <field name="UserGUID" type="String"/>
        <field name="ReaderID" type="Integer"/>
        <field name="Type" type="Integer"/>
        <field name="Modified" type="Boolean"/>
        <field name="ModifReason" type="String"/>
      </fields>
      <rows>
        <row>
          <f>3086647</f>
          <f>18091842</f>
          <f>2017-11-14</f>
          <f>21:32:10</f>
          <f>1</f>
          <f>202</f>
          <f>{ED53D55D-4B99-41F3-95BD-6945A989155C}</f>
          <f>803</f>
          <f>32</f>
          <f>null</f>
          <f>null</f>
        </row>
...


      </rows>
    </table>
  </tables>
```

I suppose it's all about xsd format or I need to perform some xml task actions. Currently in SSIS XML source (data flow task), while I'm trying to generate xsd it gives me one "f" table with data, without any marks and enumerations of fields.

[image: xml]

[image: current "f" table output]

In result I'd like to have one table containing all eleven columns.

Comment: Please do not poste pictures! Edit your question and provide a (reduced but valid) XML as *copy-n-pasteable* text. Where is this XML coming from?

Comment: @Shnugo sorry for pictures, corrected

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this will help you, but the following `T_SQL` approach would flatten your XML to an importable set. You have to rely on the implicit sorting of `<field>` and `<f>` elements, as they match only by position.

This should work with any count of table and any count of rows, as long as the table's names are unique

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<db xmlns:site="http://www.google.com">
  <params>
    <param name="parser_version" value="2" />
    <param name="data_type" value="Events" />
    <param name="created" value="2017-11-15T12:21:18" />
    <param name="program_version" value="4.5.20.1092" />
  </params>
  <tables>
    <table name="Events">
      <fields>
        <field name="UniqueID" type="Integer" />
        <field name="ID" type="AutoInc" />
        <field name="Date" type="Date" />
        <field name="Time" type="Time" />
        <field name="Code" type="Integer" />
        <field name="UserID" type="Integer" />
        <field name="UserGUID" type="String" />
        <field name="ReaderID" type="Integer" />
        <field name="Type" type="Integer" />
        <field name="Modified" type="Boolean" />
        <field name="ModifReason" type="String" />
      </fields>
      <rows>
        <row>
          <f>3086647</f>
          <f>18091842</f>
          <f>2017-11-14</f>
          <f>21:32:10</f>
          <f>1</f>
          <f>202</f>
          <f>{ED53D55D-4B99-41F3-95BD-6945A989155C}</f>
          <f>803</f>
          <f>32</f>
          <f>null</f>
          <f>null</f>
        </row>
      </rows>
    </table>
  </tables>
</db>';
```

--I assume that your XML is living within the declared variable `@xml`

```
WITH AllTablesAndFields AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY tbl.value('@name','nvarchar(max)')) AS TableInx
          ,tbl.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS TableName
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tbl.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS FieldInx
          ,fld.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS FieldName
          ,fld.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS FieldType
    FROM @xml.nodes('/db/tables/table') AS A(tbl)
    OUTER APPLY tbl.nodes('fields/field') AS B(fld)
)
,AllTablesAndRows AS
(
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY tbl.value('@name','nvarchar(max)')) AS TableInx
          ,tbl.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS TableName
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowInx
          ,rw.query('.') AS RowNode
    FROM @xml.nodes('/db/tables/table') AS A(tbl)
    OUTER APPLY tbl.nodes('rows/row') AS B(rw)
)
,AllValues AS
(
    SELECT rws.TableInx
          ,rws.TableName
          ,rws.RowInx
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rws.RowInx ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ValueInx
          ,fld.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Val
    FROM AllTablesAndRows AS rws
    OUTER APPLY rws.RowNode.nodes('row/f') AS A(fld)
)

SELECT flds.TableName
      ,flds.FieldName
      ,flds.FieldType
      ,vals.Val
FROM AllValues AS vals
FULL OUTER JOIN AllTablesAndFields AS flds ON vals.TableInx=flds.TableInx AND vals.ValueInx=flds.FieldInx;
```

The result

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| TableName | FieldName   | FieldType | Val                                    |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| Events    | UniqueID    | Integer   | 3086647                                |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| Events    | ID          | AutoInc   | 18091842                               |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| Events    | Date        | Date      | 2017-11-14                             |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| Events    | Time        | Time      | 21:32:10                               |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| Events    | Code        | Integer   | 1                                      |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| Events    | UserID      | Integer   | 202                                    |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| Events    | UserGUID    | String    | {ED53D55D-4B99-41F3-95BD-6945A989155C} |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| Events    | ReaderID    | Integer   | 803                                    |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| Events    | Type        | Integer   | 32                                     |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| Events    | Modified    | Boolean   | null                                   |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
| Events    | ModifReason | String    | null                                   |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------------+
```

Include the TableInx, FieldInx, RowInx and ValueInx to separat your result